# How to scrape data in selenium using selector

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape/get specific element of the website using selenium but i want to use css selectors instead of the XPATH i know it have a function to use CSS selector as argument but i want to use this type of selectors

```
#col-body > div > div.wrapper-info > coin-info-box > div > div > div > div.coin-properties > div:nth-child(16) > div > div.info-text.ng-binding
```

I got this type of selectors from directly from inspect element and right click and copying the selector directly how can i use those type of selector easily and directly

Comment: Can you share relevant HTML code ? we can give you more relevant CSS

Comment: @cruisepandey i want to scrap this page https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/eth/overview/BTC

Comment: Which element is that ? I could not locate `#col-body > div > div.wrapper-info > coin-info-box > div > div > div > div.coin-properties > div:nth-child(16) > div > div.info-text.ng-binding`

Comment: it is in ICO section of Overview section

Comment: They do have API access for free: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the element text you can use this locator as following:

```
element_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#col-body > div > div.wrapper-info > coin-info-box > div > div > div > div.coin-properties > div:nth-child(16) > div > div.info-text.ng-binding').text
```

However this locator seems to be very breakable and highly unreliable.
You should learn how to find correct locators, not to use automatically created locators like this.

Comment: is there any way to directly use any options given in pop up when we we right click on elements like sececor,  Xpath, Full Xpath etc. i want to scrap this site https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/eth/overview/BTC

Comment: No. At least I never heard of anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you've mentioned to not use XPath, and on similar side you are saying to have an option given in pop up .

**Instead of this CSS :**

```
#col-body > div > div.wrapper-info > coin-info-box > div > div > div > div.coin-properties > div:nth-child(16) > div > div.info-text.ng-binding
```

you can simply use :

```
div.coin-properties > div:nth-child(16)
```

Xpath you can try is :

```
//div[text()='BTC']
```

if you know the text is not going to change, you can use XPath.

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.